# Minimum sum of multiple source-destination path

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimization

Given an undirected and unweighted graph, I want to find out the minimum sum of k pair of source-destination path, under the constraint that each vertex is used at most once.

For example, the following graph with 2 pair source-destination (A, E) and (B, F) has minimum sum of 7 steps. That is, (A > G > H > I > E) = 4 steps and (B > C > D > F) = 3 steps.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAbh6.png

It is obviously that greedy method of finding all these k path sequentially will result in suboptimal solution. For example, there exists a solution of 8 steps with (A > C > D > E) = 3 steps and (B > J > K > L > M > F) = 5 steps.

I have consider to model this problem into minimum cost maximum flow problem. However, such multiple source-destination pair cannot always be distinguished. For example, if k = 2 and the two pairs are (A, B) and (C, D), the solution applying MCMF may result in (A > ... > D) and (B > ... > C) under some situation, which is apparently not the solution I want.

Is there any idea about this problem?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a modified multi-agent path planning problem. Normally agents are just restricted not to collide or cross paths, but in your version they cannot share vertices anywhere. It wouldn't be hard to modify the [CBS](http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/AAAI/AAAI12/paper/viewFile/5062/5239) algorithm to solve this problem.

I'm going to call your *k* paths *agents* to help describe a solution.

The basic idea is that you use a binary search tree to find the solution. Start by finding the shortest path for each of the *k* agents independently. Then, you check to see if you have any collisions between agents in the solved paths. When you find a node shared by two paths, you branch in the tree. On the right side of the tree the first agent is forbidden from using that node. On the left side of the tree the second agent is forbidden from using the node. Then, the agent that has been given a new constraint is required to re-search without using the given node.

Nodes in the tree are expanded in a best-first order according to the total path cost of all agents. When you find a solution, it is guaranteed to be optimal.

There are other algorithms you could use, but this one is pretty simple as it keeps the planning decoupled. The efficiency depends on the exact nature of the problems you are solving.

If I had to guess, the problem is NP-Hard or NP-Complete - easy to verify solutions, but the given algorithm runs in exponential time.

Comment: I will check out this paper these days,
and thanks for your answering!